# Can I create the full text as an index along with NGramFilterFactory

Tags: solr, full-text-search, solr4, n-gram

I defined a field type **text_ngram**.

```xml
<fieldType name="text_ngram" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="15"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

I know how NGramFilterFactory works. Say we have a text `Solr search in Stackoverflow`. Now as per the field definition, after lowercasing the whole text, it'll start creating index like `sol,olr,lr ,r s, se,....`. But it'll not keep the whole text as a token or create an index for that.

My question is ..

**Is there a way to create an index for the whole string as well as the tokens created by NGramFilterFactory?**

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot. Have a look into [the JavaDoc of the NGramFilterFactory](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_7_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/ngram/NGramFilterFactory.html), there is no parameter to set like `keepword`.

What you can do

- add a new field in your `schema.xml`
- [make a `<copyField ... />`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Copying+Fields) for that new field to feed it with data

That new field may have any field type you want. When searching go for dismax or edismax to spread the search input over all fields you have content in.